# mongoose find query with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, find

I am trying to verify verification code while registering user. Query have multiple conditions. if document is returned, then verification code is verified else not. Problem from below snippet, it always satisfy if(foundUser) although document is not returned.

```
UserModel
        .find({
            email,
            verificationCode: code
        },
        (err, foundUser) => {
            if(err) {
                return res.json({msg: "Error"})
            }
            else {
                console.log('foundUser', foundUser)
                if(foundUser) {
                    return res.json({msg: "found email + code"})
                }
                else {
                    return res.json({msg: "No email & code matched"})
                }

            }
        })
```

Comment: what does your foundUser Log?

Comment: @EugeneSunic console output is **foundUser []**

Comment: Well, what do you expect... your if should look like this: if (foundUser.length!==0){}
I assume result is not yielded because of code value perhaps...

Comment: @EugeneSunicn Thank you very much. It worked and saved tons of time :)

Comment: Then I ll post an answer so that you can accept with minor code improvement xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foundUser can be written in 3 ways

```
  if (foundUser.length !== 0) {}
  if (!foundUser.length) {}
  if (foundUser.length > 0) {}
```

Choose the one which suits you best.

I would suggest option number 2

```
UserModel
            .find({
                email,
                verificationCode: code
            },
            (err, foundUser) => {
                if(err) {
                    return res.json({msg: "Error"})
                }
                else {
                    console.log('foundUser', foundUser)
                    if (!foundUser.length) {
                        return res.json({msg: "found email + code"})
                    }
                    else {
                        return res.json({msg: "No email & code matched"})
                    }

                }
            })
```

Comment: It seems that in `find({email, verificationCode: code },...` there is not valid object.